# What is Platform Bus in Embedded Systems?

Tags: arm, embedded, bus

I would want to know what is the Platform bus in SoC . I have seen some device driver implementation in Linux kernel where drivers are registered with platform bus or rather should i say these all called platform driver where devices sits on platform bus.

But what are the platform bus?

Is Amba bus platform bus for ARM bus SoC's?

Answer (score 2):

*I'm not particularly a Linux or SoC developer, but I think this answer is correct:*

Yes, the AMBA bus is the platform bus when it is used.

In [/drivers/of/platform.c](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/of/platform.c) (line 29) when CONFIG_ARM_AMBA is set then the AMBA bus is used in creating the device tree. CONFIG_ARM_AMBA is set in the [ARM config file](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/arm/Kconfig), but it looks like it is only available on some devices.

There's a concise description of what the platform bus is for in the Linux kernel [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/driver-model/platform.txt).

Comment: Also, there is a duplicate of this question on stack overflow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23783649/what-is-platform-bus-in-embedded-systems). I'll let more experienced people decide what to do with that.

Comment: I've flagged the duplicate on the StackOverflow.  StackOverflow mods will take care of it.